# Is there any way to attach subtitles in YouTube videos?

Tags: youtube, subtitles

While watching YouTube videos online I need subtitles but they are not attached to YouTube videos. I have subtitles files in my machine.

Is there any way to attach subtitles from your system to YouTube videos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to add subtitles to the video being played, you can use the chrome extension [YouTube SubTitles](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/youtube-subtitles/dblpdenjapnbppelpaflghkfblfhgobo)

This plugin allows to attach .srt files to the YouTube videos.

If the videos are uploaded by you on your account, then you can use [Youtube video editor](http://www.youtube.com/editor%E2%80%8E) to add [captions](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2734796?hl=en&ref_topic=3014331). You can upload srt, sub etc. files for captions.

Answer (score 2):

I have created a Chrome extension for the same purpose.

You can check it out here: [Subtitles For Youtube](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/subtitles-for-youtube/oanhbddbfkjaphdibnebkklpplclomal)

Answer (score 1):

An overlay subtitle player is a more general solution in case you are watching videos not only on Youtube.

I developed [Penguin Subtitle Player](https://github.com/carsonip/Penguin-Subtitle-Player) which is an open-source, cross-platform standalone subtitle player. It supports all Windows, Linux and Mac OSX. It can always stay on top of flash player and HTML5 full screen so using it with online videos has no problem.

Comment: Please see our [help/behavior]. If you are affiliated with a product/service you are recommending, you need to disclose your affiliation in your answer.